# Content Type's in bolt

Tags: javascript, symfony, url-routing, content-type, bolt-cms

I am trying to give 2 content types the same singular slug in bolt. both of them should have the same fields, and the same template. at this point i use the `record_template:` tag to set the default template for each content type.

```
vervolgpagina:
  name: vervolgpagina
  singular_slug: graszoden
  singular_name: vervolg
  fields:
      titel:
          type: text
          class: large
          group: Content
      slug:
          type: slug
          uses: titel
          group: Content
      body:
          type: html
          height: 500px
          group: Content
      meta_keywords:
          type: text
          group: SEO
          label: "Meta keywords"
      meta_description:
          type: textarea
          height: 50px
          group: SEO
          label: "Meta description"
  record_template: vervolgpagina.twig

graszoden:
  name: graszoden
  singular_slug: graszoden
  singular_name: gras
  fields:
      titel:
          type: text
          class: large
          group: Content
      slug:
          type: slug
          uses: titel
          group: Content
      body:
          type: html
          height: 500px
          group: Content
      meta_keywords:
          type: text
          group: SEO
          label: "Meta keywords"
      meta_description:
          type: textarea
          height: 50px
          group: SEO
          label: "Meta description"
  record_template: vervolgpagina.twig
```

so if i just put in one of the two content types and add a page to it then it
redirects me to `/graszoden/vervolgpagina`

so if i add the secont content type and add another page to it `/graszoden/randomexample`

what happends now. is that the page that worked just fine. says ERROR 404, and the other page gives me an bolt error with "No listing.twig file specified."

is there a way to show a content type twice in the cms with other names? Or is there a way to give two content types the same singular slug?

Thanx in advance,

Comment: Not that I have much clue what this is about, but reads like a nice question ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat The question is about the routing bolt-cms uses. its a fixed bunch of standard routes but this question goes on about how to break open the standard and create our own routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. If you have two contenttypes with the same slug and same fields, it should really just be one CT.

Perhaps what you might want is a "Grouping Taxonomy", see the example in taxonomy.yml for that.

Comment: Ok i will look into it. Thank you for your reaction :3

Answer (score 1):

After some more projects in bolt using twig ive got some other solution.

If you want to use singular slugs multiple times u are forced to create a listing page. But with this you will not have to. Just create an local extension and fill in the part highlighted at the end in this answer.

**[Link to sourcecode](https://github.com/Postitief/Bolt-Match-All-routes)** No readme yet. But I hope the explanation here is good enough.

Here is the extension file code (This code is litteraly all the functionality, you will have to create a local extension for this to work ):

```
class MatchAllController
{
/**
 * The bolt application
 *
 * @var
 */
protected $app;

/**
 * The path to the config.yml
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $configPath = __DIR__ . '/../../config/config.yml';

public function matchAll(Request $request, $slug, Application $application)
{
    $this->app = $application;

//        var_dump($this->getConfig());die;
    $contentTypes = ['provincies', 'vervolg'];

    foreach($contentTypes as $contentType)
    {
        if(null !== $result = $this->record($request, $contentType, $slug)) {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    $this->abort(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, "Page $slug not found.");
    return null;
}

protected function getConfig()
{
    return Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($this->configPath));
}

public function record(Request $request, $contenttypeslug, $slug = '')
{
    $contenttype = $this->getContentType($contenttypeslug);

    // Perhaps we don't have a slug. Let's see if we can pick up the 'id', instead.
    if (empty($slug)) {
        $slug = $request->get('id');
    }

    $slug = $this->app['slugify']->slugify($slug);

    // First, try to get it by slug.
    $content = $this->getContent($contenttype['slug'], ['slug' => $slug, 'returnsingle' => true, 'log_not_found' => !is_numeric($slug)]);

    if (!$content && is_numeric($slug)) {
        // And otherwise try getting it by ID
        $content = $this->getContent($contenttype['slug'], ['id' => $slug, 'returnsingle' => true]);
    }

    // No content, no page!
    if (!$content) {
        return null;
    }

    // Then, select which template to use, based on our 'cascading templates rules'
    $template = $this->templateChooser()->record($content);

    // Setting the canonical URL.
    if ($content->isHome() && ($template === $this->getOption('general/homepage_template'))) {
        $url = $this->app['resources']->getUrl('rooturl');
    } else {
        $url = $this->app['resources']->getUrl('rooturl') . ltrim($content->link(), '/');
    }
    $this->app['resources']->setUrl('canonicalurl', $url);

    // Setting the editlink
    $this->app['editlink'] = $this->generateUrl('editcontent', ['contenttypeslug' => $contenttype['slug'], 'id' => $content->id]);
    $this->app['edittitle'] = $content->getTitle();

    // Make sure we can also access it as {{ page.title }} for pages, etc. We set these in the global scope,
    // So that they're also available in menu's and templates rendered by extensions.
    $globals = [
        'record'                      => $content,
        $contenttype['singular_slug'] => $content,
    ];

    return $this->render($template, [], $globals);
}

/**
 * Get the contenttype as an array, based on the given slug.
 *
 * @param string $slug
 *
 * @return boolean|array
 */
protected function getContentType($slug)
{
    return $this->storage()->getContentType($slug);
}

/**
 * Returns the Entity Manager.
 *
 * @return \Bolt\Storage\EntityManager
 */
protected function storage()
{
    return $this->app['storage'];
}

/**
 * Shortcut to abort the current request by sending a proper HTTP error.
 *
 * @param integer $statusCode The HTTP status code
 * @param string  $message    The status message
 * @param array   $headers    An array of HTTP headers
 *
 * @throws HttpExceptionInterface
 */
protected function abort($statusCode, $message = '', array $headers = [])
{
    $this->app->abort($statusCode, $message, $headers);
}

/**
 * Shortcut for {@see \Bolt\Legacy\Storage::getContent()}
 *
 * @param string $textquery
 * @param array  $parameters
 * @param array  $pager
 * @param array  $whereparameters
 *
 * @return \Bolt\Legacy\Content|\Bolt\Legacy\Content[]
 *
 * @see \Bolt\Legacy\Storage::getContent()
 */
protected function getContent($textquery, $parameters = [], &$pager = [], $whereparameters = [])
{
    return $this->storage()->getContent($textquery, $parameters, $pager, $whereparameters);
}

/**
 * Return the Bolt\TemplateChooser provider.
 *
 * @return \Bolt\TemplateChooser
 */
protected function templateChooser()
{
    return $this->app['templatechooser'];
}

/**
 * Shortcut for {@see UrlGeneratorInterface::generate}
 *
 * @param string $name          The name of the route
 * @param array  $params        An array of parameters
 * @param int    $referenceType The type of reference to be generated (one of the constants)
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function generateUrl($name, $params = [], $referenceType = UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH)
{
    /** @var UrlGeneratorInterface $generator */
    $generator = $this->app['url_generator'];

    return $generator->generate($name, $params, $referenceType);
}

/**
 * Renders a template
 *
 * @param string $template  the template name
 * @param array  $variables array of context variables
 * @param array  $globals   array of global variables
 *
 * @return \Bolt\Response\BoltResponse
 */
protected function render($template, array $variables = [], array $globals = [])
{
    return $this->app['render']->render($template, $variables, $globals);
}
}
```

Becouse this is an new starting project. The only thing that is variable is this part

```
public function matchAll(Request $request, $slug, Application $application)
{
$this->app = $application;

//Fill your costum routes in here
$contentTypes = ['VARIABLE SINGULAR SLUG', 'VARIABLE SINGULAR SLUG 2'];

foreach($contentTypes as $contentType)
{
    if(null !== $result = $this->record($request, $contentType, $slug)) {
        return $result;
    }
}

$this->abort(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, "Page $slug not found.");
return null;
}
```

> $contentTypes = ['VARIABLE SINGULAR SLUG', 'VARIABLE SINGULAR SLUG 2'];

This particular piece of code is where u fill in the singular slug u want to use. It can contain infinite slugs

Hope this helps someone else later on. Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this could really help other people. You are basically saying: one can program a solution ...

Comment: @GhostCat yes sorry im working on putting this extension online so I can put link in the answer

Comment: That sounds better. Although: you might want to include some summary into the answer - as "link only" answers are discouraged; as you know: links tend to break.

Comment: hmm its an extension for bolt ill try to give a run on it trough here but it will be a lot of code but as u say. links tend to break.

Comment: Sure. Balancing is required. This site is not a source code repository. So linking to github or wherever is fine. But explaining the basics of your solution would make a great answer .

Comment: @GhostCat full extension code is here now I guess people will get a rough idea on how to get this to work now. :)